# Visibility trouble with framelayout children

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-view, android-framelayout

I have a problem with the children of my FrameLayout when I change their visibility **dynamically** :

The FrameLayout is composed with a simple `ScrollView` that is allways visible and a `RelativeLayout` that represents a search bar and that is gone by default but that can be set to visible dynamically if the user press a button on the action bar.

So when the user press the action bar button and the search bar is `GONE`, there is no problem, the search bar appears like it has to. But when the search bar is `VISIBLE` impossible to make her disappear. I don't know why because the state of the bar is well set to `GONE` when I display it in the log but it's like the `FrameLayout` was not refreshed.

Someone knows that probleme or has a solution to mine ?

There is the code:

```
  ....

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout_movie_detail"
    android:layout_below="@+id/movie_actionbar">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

               ....

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_movie_detail_poster"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image" />

                ....

         </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_search_bar_movie"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        layout="@layout/search_bar" />

 </FrameLayout>

  ....
```

search_bar.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 

  <EditText />

  <ImageButton />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the code to display and hide the search bar:

```
    private void onDisplaySearchBar() {
       if (search_bar.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
          search_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       else
          search_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

       search_bar.invalidate();
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Can you paste the dynamic modification code?
And try to `invalidate()` the `RelativeLayout` to be sure it is redrawn.

Comment: @eyal-lezmy yes I tried but it's the same result

Comment: If you change View.GONE to View.INVISIBLE and it will work, you can find an answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355582/what-is-difference-b-w-view-gone-and-view-invisible