# what is difference b/w View.GONE and View.INVISIBLE

Tags: android, textview

I am using a Custom View. 
  On the Custom View I am plotting some Graph. And also I am using TextView on my layout. When I am making this TextView VISIBLE and INVISIBLE on button click
, it is clearing graph.Why  it is clearing  graph with both GONE and INVISIBLE?

Any Idea?

Answer (score 5):

From [Android official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html),

> View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for
>   layout purposes.
>
> View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for
>   layout purposes.